# Как сделать всплывающее окошко с содержимым прямо над ссылкой при ее наведении?

Tags: jquery, всплывающее-окно, html, css

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать всплывающее окошко с содержимым (картинка, текст, ссылка, не примитивный tooltip) прямо над ссылкой при наведении на нее?

Проблема в том, что у `notefication_tooltip` обрезается верхушка, позиционируется он не относительно ссылки, а относительно большого блока (`position:relative` не выручает) и гаснет сразу при отведении мышки - не дает перейти по ссылке *Go to community wall*.

Буду благодарен за помощь и подсказки!

```
<h4 class="media-heading">in reply to your post <a class="noteficaion_href" href="#fakelink">Google is soo bad..</a></h4> 
<div class="notefication_tooltip"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <img src="avatar-18.jpg" class="social-avatar img-circle" alt="Avatar">
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-9"> 
      <a href="#fakelink">Alexey</a> on <a href="#fakelink">Vera's wall</a> 
      <p class="small"> Google is so bad..Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <p class="notefication_tooltip_p">
    <i class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i> Go to community wall
  </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: hint - непримитивный тултип возникает не над ссылкой, а сам выбирает себе место, вот на этом сайте наведите на тэг например.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8yp8pgse/

```
<a href="#" class="main_link">Ссылка <i class="tooltip">Я тултип</i></a>
.tooltip {
    display: none;
}

.main_link:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
    /*плюс эффекты и позиционирование*/
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то именно динамическое позиционирование и есть суть вопроса а не то, как его показать/спрятать